# How to call a method from another one?

Tags: c#, icsharpcode

I'm working on a code-editor and I want to call the string *line* into a keyargs event which is inside another void-returning method.

Output should occur when I type enter key, and then the selected-list from ComboBox should append to text held in RichTextBox.

Now to fulfill that, I'd like to ask you, how to call this method:

```
void Parse()
    {
        String inputLanguage =

          "using System;\n" + "\n" +
          "public class Stuff : Form { \n" +
          "  public static void Main(String args) {\n" +
          "\n" + "\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "}\n";

        // Foreach line in input,
        // identify key words and format them when adding to the rich text box.
        Regex r = new Regex("\\n");
        String[] lines = r.Split(inputLanguage);
        foreach (string l in lines)
        {
            ParseLine(l);
        }
    }
void ParseLine(string line)
{
    Regex r = new Regex("([ \\t{}();])");
    String[] tokens = r.Split(line);

    foreach (string token in tokens)
    {

        // Set the token's default color and font.
        rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
        rtb.SelectionFont = new Font("Courier New", 10, FontStyle.Regular);

        // Check for a comment.
        if (token == "//" || token.StartsWith("//"))
        {
            // Find the start of the comment and then extract the whole comment.
            int index = line.IndexOf("//");

            rtb.SelectedText = comment;
            break;
        }

        // Check whether the token is a keyword. 
        var keywordsDef = new KeyWord();
        String[] keywords = keywordsDef.keywords;

        for (int i = 0; i < keywords.Length; i++)
        {
            if (keywords[i] == token)
            {
                // Apply alternative color and font to highlight keyword.
                HighlighType.keywordsType(rtb);
                break;
            }
        }
        rtb.SelectedText = token;
    }
    rtb.SelectedText = "\n";
}
```

from within this one:

```
void lb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            lb.Visible = false;
            lb.Items.Clear();
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            //ParseLine(string line);
            Parse();

            string comment = line.Substring(index, line.Length - index);

            rtb.SelectedText = comment + " " + lb.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I really need help. Big thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the problem with commented line? I mean `//ParseLine(string line);`

Comment: 3errors appears, invalid expression term 'string', invalid expression term ')' and ; expected

Comment: Haven't noticed first time. It should be: `ParseLine(line);` You don't need to specify types in method call.

Comment: yeah i already do that, 5errors appears The name 'line' does not exist inthe current context(x3) , The name 'index' does not exist in the current context(x2) .

Comment: Please use correct terms. You don't have "something is within a void", and you don't "call a void". These things you're talking about are called *methods* or *functions*. `void` is a placeholder for "no data returned". If a method returns an `int` you don't say "I have this within the int", do you?

Comment: Does it compile with this line commented out (as shown in question body)?

Comment: but everytime i runs it out it always pointing the word 'line' w/c is in this void ParseLine(string line) .how can i call line without using the void statement?

Comment: You're passing the parameter wrong. When calling the method, you can not specify a type. See my answer. Also: where's the `index` variable declared? I can't see it...

Comment: There is NO VOID STATEMENT. `void` is a special "kind of data", similar to `int` or `string`. You do not use "void" in function calls. In function CALLs you use: function NAME and ARGUMENTS/PARAMETERS. The function runs and either (a)produces a result and returns it, or (b)returns 'nothing', 'void'. Compare `public string MakeDoubleText(string text) { return text+text; }` versus `public void DoPing(string howLoud) {  pinger.Ping(howLoud);  }`. The first one produces result, the second - just performs something and does not return any value. Hence, the RESULT of the second is VOID.

Comment: so how can i do that sir? how can i call the string line?

Comment: To call those two functions I've included above you use only their names and parameters:  `MakeDouble("Mom");` or `DoPing("very");`. Please note that there is not a single difference. This is the method call, it does not use any "void" things here. The difference between value-returning and void-returning function is visible only when you actually **try receiving** the produced result: `string result = MakeDouble("Mom");` or `string result = DoPing("very");` -- the former will compile, the latter **will not compile** and fail with errors - that's because it  "returns VOID" not string.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the parameter wrong. You can not pass a type when calling a method. The commented line should read

```
ParseLine(line);
```

The variable `line` must be declared somewhere above `ParseLine`. What it contains is up to you, but probably you want to set

```
string line = lb.Text;
```

So your code could read like this:

```
void lb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        lb.Visible = false;
        lb.Items.Clear();
    }

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        string line = lb.Text;
        ParseLine(line);
        //Parse();

        string comment = line.Substring(index, line.Length - index);
        rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
        rtb.SelectionFont = new Font("Courier New", 10, FontStyle.Italic);
        rtb.SelectedText = comment + " " + lb.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: as ive mention in comment above after i declare that 5errors appear .The name 'line' does not exist inthe current context(x3) , The name 'index' does not exist in the current context(x2) . . . just a problemwithin this line >>> string comment = line.Substring(index, line.Length - index); <<< source was always this: void ParseLine(string line), how can i call the string line without using void?

Comment: Yes, well where *is* `index` declared? I can't see it and neither can the compiler. Also, if you declare it correctly as in my code, there first error can not occur - you're declaring `line` in the wrong place I bet. Update your question with the current code.

Comment: if (token == "//" || token.StartsWith("//"))
            {
                // Find the start of the comment and then extract the whole comment.
                int index = line.IndexOf("//");
                string comment = line.Substring(index, line.Length - index);
               
                rtb.SelectedText = comment;
                break;
            }

Comment: It seems you're lacking basic understanding of "variable scopes". A variable is only valid in the block where it is declared and any block below that. Just because you have `index` declared *somewhere* doesn't mean you can use it *anywhere*.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the function is not the problem, but you need some way of retrieving the current line in whichever editor you're using. Once you have retrieved it, you can call `ParseLine` on it, but until you have it you have nothing to work on.